# Angular2: Interpolation not rendering

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am following an Angular 2 crash course. 
I have node v7.10.0 and npm 4.2.0 installed. Starting from a 'hello World' app with a root app.component.ts, I've created a simple custom component test.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
        selector: 'test',
        template: `<h2>{{ title }}</h2>`
})

export class TestComponent {
        title: "Just testing ...";
}
```

I import and reference TestComponent in the root component of the app (app.component.ts):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {TestComponent} from './test.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1><test></test>',
    directives: [TestComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

It only renders "Hello Angular 2" in the browser, not the "Just testing ..." string.

I was thinking that the problem could be in the templates (backticks or similar) , but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.
The console spits a couple of deprecation warnings, but don't seem related to my rendering problem:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
angular2.dev.js:353 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
```

Comment: Aren't you getting any errors? Can you share your `app.module` please?

Comment: `directives` is completely obsolete. The component must be declared in the declarations of the module. angular2/core is completely obsolete, to. It seems you're using a beta version of angular 2, when the current stable version is Angular 4.x. Don't learn things that are already obsolete.

Comment: Also this code seems to be following an earlier relaese of Angular2. Please follow these https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/ for the latest.

Comment: As everyone mentioned, you are using the beta version of angular2. You should upgrade to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for angular 4.0.0

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { TestComponent }  from './test.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1><test></test>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `<h2>{{ title }}</h2>`
})

export class TestComponent {
    title = 'Just testing ...';
}
```